# como crear una variable nueva con mutate?

Tags: r

Cómo crear una variable nueva con la función mutate?

He intentado de la siguiente  forma :

got%>%
mutate(variable=variable2,TRUE,FALSE)

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Pues una variable nueva es así: `got%>% mutate(variable=variable2)`, pero no sé que es lo que buscan los valores `TRUE` y `FALSE`  dentro del `mutate` ¿podrías explicar que es lo que buscas?